# Is the Facebook Graph Api fast enough? (PHP SDK)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

At the moment I'm working on my first website with Facebook Graph functionality, so I'm new to all this. I'm using the PHP SDK in combination with Javascript SDK.

I'm wondering, is calling the Facebook API fast enough to deliver userdata such as id/name/picture etc. or should I retrieve the data once after login and save it in my own database or a session or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

that usually depends on your own definition on "fast".
Once I have done a project, the page transition take usually 1.5 sec.  To me, that is acceptable...
how, client expect it to be 0.5 sec.

Just in case you find the performance not acceptable, you can consider to add a caching layer in your app to speed things up.